# CSS, jQuery, Mosaic combo Issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, mosaic

I'm having issues relating to the CSS in this web project. The site is coded in PHP but in this example I just posted the relevant HTML.

I've compiled my CSS (compiled from .SCSS) and attached the entire CSS file.

Here is the fiddle - THE ENTIRE CSS FILE
     Second fiddle - JUST THE MOSAIC CSS

> [edit]
>   **To Clarify:**
>   There are three images here aligned next to each other spaced out by 10px. The mosaic jquery plugin, during a hover state animates a header text upwards and brings into view a p element text. Also, there is a grayscale filter on hover via the css. 
> **The Issue is** that something went awry in my CSS editing and now the pictures will not even show up. There is nothing displayed.
>   **What CSS property is causing these images to not be displayed?**

Comment: Can you clarify what the issues are, specifically?

Comment: I've added more details. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `display: none` from mosaic-backdrop in your css.  This is causing the images to not display:-

http://jsfiddle.net/aTTL4/5/